# jquery ui icons

Tags: jquery-ui, user-interface, icons

I am working with jquery ui and their icons.

My icons looks like this (except I have another theme): [jquery ui icons chart](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tests/static/icons.html)

But I found this site with a set of nice icons which I would like to use (srcroll down to the bottom of the page): [Michael Keck](http://www.michaelkeck.de/projects/jquery/)

Can these icons be found and downloaded somewhere? Do they belong to the jquery ui framework or are they customized and only exists on this site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He's essentially created his own theme with that set of icons. That's the beauty of the jQuery UI CSS framework, it specifies a list of icons and you can choose to overwrite them without having to change any of your HTML markup or JS code.

Comment: Ok. So how do you create your own theme? The themeroller at jqueryui.com only provides an option to change the color on the icons. How do you create icons with small images? Do you have to draw your own image in Photoshop, GIMP or similar software?

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to create a new sprite map that overwrites the various `theme/images/ui-icons_*_256x240.png`